# How to restrict due date higher than start date using Kendo DatePicker?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am using AngularJS for Kendo DatePicker with input fields, how can I set cycle due date higher than selected start date? How to achieve this task using Kendo DatePicker with AngularJS?

cycle.html

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 fieldHeight">
    <label for="cycleStart" class="col-md-4 required">Cycle Start</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
            <input kendo-date-picker
            type="text" class="form-control" id="cycleStart"
            name="cycleStart" 
            ng-model="rcsa" 
            required data-required-msg="Cycle start is required">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6 fieldHeight">
    <label for="cycleEnd" class="col-md-4 required">Cycle end (due date)</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input 
        kendo-date-picker
        type="text" class="form-control" id="cycleStart"
        name="cycleEnd"
        ng-model="rcsaCyclEnd"
        required data-required-msg="Cycle end date is required">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set date picker due date `min` property value with `cyclestart` value.
Change your date picker code like this :

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 fieldHeight">
    <label for="cycleStart" class="col-md-4 required">Cycle Start</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input kendo-date-picker
               type="text" class="form-control" id="cycleStart"
               name="cycleStart" 
               ng-model="rcsa" k-ng-model="rcsaObject" <!-- need this porperty -->
               required data-required-msg="Cycle start is required">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6 fieldHeight">
    <label for="cycleEnd" class="col-md-4 required">Cycle end (due date)</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input kendo-date-picker
               type="text" class="form-control" id="cycleStart"
               name="cycleEnd"
               ng-model="rcsaCyclEnd"
               k-min="rcsaObject" k-rebind="rcsaObject" <!-- add this line -->
               required data-required-msg="Cycle end date is required">
    </div>
</div>
```

We need `k-ng-model` to store date object of `cycleStart` whereas `ng-model` only store its string value, then `rcsaObject` will be used to set `cycleEnd` `min` property. And `k-rebind` will reconstruct our date picker to use new value of min property if `rcsaObject` value is changed.

Comment: Is it right approach to use ng-model and k-ng-model on same element ?

Comment: `ng-model` and `k-ng-model` is just a way to store your data. It is same as how you declare a variable in a code, if you don't need it then you shouldn't use it, because `k-min` need a `date` object value instead of `string` value then you need a way to get that from the date picker. If you don't need a string value, then you could dispose `ng-model` attribute.

Comment: Thanks that resolve the issue with due date user can not select less than start date..but he can type previous date in input... Any idea how to restrict user to enter date manually ?